# when make depend,error:make: *** No rule to make target `depend'

Tags: makefile, ubuntu-14.04

system:Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
I was installing OpenLDAP, when I got

```
:make depend error:make: *** No rule to make target `depend'.  Stop.
```

How can I get rid of this error.

Comment: Please reformat your question so we can understand your question.

Comment: Please make it more clear as it not readable. Not able to understand what you asking.

Comment: If you are installing from source did you do `./configure` ?